# Error: java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Tags: junit

I am facing one problem while running the Junit scripts. I am getting the below error message.

I have three java classes under which i have commented all the @Test annotations from Class A and Class B but have four @Test annotations in Class C..but still it is showing the below error message.

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

```
Error: java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
 at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.<init>(Parameterized.java:171)
 at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.createRunnersForParameters(Parameterized.java:319)
 at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:282)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please help here?

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: How do you start your tests (IDE, Maven, ...)?

Answer (score 11):

Ensure that all of your relevant test case objects are `public` and non-`abstract`, and that your test methods are annotated with `@Test` but are also `public void` and non-`static`.

See more at the [JUnit Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: I had a base class for all tests that was **not** `abstract`. Solved by making it abstract.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have this import:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

instead of:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

As well as the following annotations on test class if your project is SpringBoot 2:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue "Error: java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods" in my simple Spring-boot project. I resolved the issue by doing the following steps.

1. Make sure that the the test class is in src/test/java folder. In my project settings the Test class was in src/test folder.
2. Make sure that src/test/java is in Java Build Path. Go to *Project->properties->Java Build Path ->source*  and add src/test/java folder.
3. Test class should be in same package as the source Java class with main method.

Comment: The last one, having the test class in the same package as my main method, is what tripped me up.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you import the right package :

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
```

and not the testng package